# How can I make a barcode pdf generate in c#?

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to generate barcode and this barcode I want to keep some values(author,bookname,pagenumber,author).Because 
When the barcode is read you want the author,bookname,page number and book shelf number to come up to see those values.
So when creating, I want it to be created with 3 values.

**When I press the Create button when I enter a value in the textbox, I can create a barcode.
But my problem is this. There is a database table (table name: books) in 10 books.
To print the barcode of the author, bookname, pagenumber, author fields in this table with 10 records.
I want to pull the data and write it into qr code.**

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            using (SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog() {Filter = "JPEG|*.jpg", ValidateNames = true})
            {
                if (sfd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    MessagingToolkit.QRCode.Codec.QRCodeEncoder encoder=new QRCodeEncoder();
                    encoder.QRCodeScale = 8;
                    Bitmap bmp = encoder.Encode(textBox1.Text);
                    pictureBox1.Image = bmp;
                    bmp.Save(sfd.FileName,ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                }
            }
    }
```

Comment: Sorry, SO doesn't solve homework tasks.

Comment: A barcode is a series of numbers that normally is a ID to the real information. It in itself doesn't hold any real info, especially not 4 lots of data strings that could be lengthy. You might want to look more into QR Codes or something similar. There are lots of generators online you could probably API into, save as a image to insert into your PDF.

Comment: Hello.I'm sorry.Not homework.I am developing a library project to improve myself.So I want to learn how to do it, not a general code.

Comment: @Seige Thank you for the information you provided

Answer (score 0):

Pdf417 is very easy...
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Pdf417EncoderLibrary/

then pdf with 
https://selectpdf.com/pdf-library-for-net/

Comment: If possible can you please share example/code.